# What permissions do I need to get RoleAssignments via the rest api?

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest

I am trying to get the ACL on a file via the rest api.
I can get the contents of a file and make other rest calls but when I call:

```
https://foo.sharepoint.com/_api/Web/Lists(guid'...')/Items(...)/FirstUniqueAncestorSecurableObject?$expand=RoleAssignments
```

or just
https://foo.sharepoint.com/_api/Web/RoleAssignments
I get a `401 Unauthorized Entity` response.

I have created an appPrinciple in the site, and during the oAuth initiation I am requesting the `AllSites.Manage` permission. Around a year ago this code worked - and I can't find anything that suggests that this is no longer allowed.
Can anyone shed any light?

Comment: Are you using the same client secret as a year ago?

Comment: Hi Kai, No this is a new appPrinciple I just created, using th _layouts/15/AppRegNew.aspx

Comment: Are you sure you can, for example, read list title? 401 normally says something wrong with authentication. 403 says something wrong with permissions

Comment: Yes I can get full information for lists / sites etc, so https://foo.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists(guid'...') works just fine.  From There I can get the list item, and also the call to FirstUniqueAncestorSecurableObject on the list item works, just not when I expand to get RoleAssignments

Comment: Does your user have permissions to modify role assignments?

Comment: This is probably where my understanding breaks down! I don't have a user, the sharepoint rest service is being consumed from a remote java process using the client id / secret of the appPrinciple I created using AppRegNew.  I didn't add any permissions to the appPrinciple, my understanding is that these are requested dynamically during the oAuth workflow. I'm requesting AllSites.Manage ( tenency level manage ) which I think is the highest level I can request using this mechanism ( you can't request FullControl via oAuth ).

Comment: I did try adding other permissions to the app directly using appInv from the admin user (foo-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/AppInv.aspx) but at that point I was just throwing things at the wall to see if anything would stick

Answer (score 1):

I finally found out what I was doing wrong:
It seems that to get RolePermissions you need a higher level of access than you can request from oAuth, you need to put those permissions onto the AppPrinciple you are using. From the admin site: 
 e.g. https://foo-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/AppInv.aspx

Find your app then enter the following XML code into the box 'Permission Request XML' and click create - then authorise the app.

```
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
<AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/tenant" Right="Read" />
<AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection" Right="FullControl" />
<AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web" Right="FullControl" /></AppPermissionRequests>
```

Comment: Just an fyi, if you grant full control to the site collection, you don't need to do the same for web.

Comment: Well it worked for a couple of weeks then stopped working again with no changes on either side, also for QA with a completely separate deployment. All signs point to a bug on the sharepoint side.